# Transparent gif blurring when saving for web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, export

I'm editing out the background of a gif for the first time (I've done it for pictures before) and I noticed when i save for web the layers that have been edited start to blur together.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Realize no one here knows what the gif is *supposed* to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Editing out your background makes your layers transparent. Transparent layers show the layers beneath it (because they are... uh... transparent). So they seem to "merge" when you export them.

You need to change your setup so that **only one layer is visible at a time**.

Comment: Also, may I ask why you edit out the background of a gif you found on the web?